# Inequalities for convex functions

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis

I've come up with an approach for generating inequalities for real-valued convex functions that allows one to produce inequalities that don't seem to look obvious. What I would like to know is whether they could be proved by elementary methods.

For example, I proved the following result: if $f(x)$ is convex on the interval $[0, 1]$, then

$f(0)+5f(1/6)+5f(1/2)+f(1) \ge 4(f(1/8)+f(1/3)+f(5/8))$.

My question is: can this inequality be proved by well-known/elementary methods/formulas?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you know majorization (in the context of convex functions)?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with this approach (e. g. Karamata inequality).

Comment: This is a direct consequence of Karamata. You just have to check that $\sum x_i \geq \sum y_i$, which is true in this case. I consider Karamata elemntary for convex functions, since it characterizes the obvious idea of "Using only moves where 2 points are brought closer to each other by the same amount, when can we transform one set to another?".

Comment: @Calvin: Thank you very much! In a hindsight, I should have asked a similar question using a more complex example illustrating my approach.

Comment: Can you state your example / approach then? I do believe that in almost all cases, it can be reduced to "moving 2 points closer", otherwise we can construct a convex function that violates the inequality.

Comment: @Calvin: I will provide more details somewhat later, as I'm in a rush right now. Regarding the idea of "moving 2 points closer" ... What sources could you recommend where this general idea is discussed/illustrated  in the context of convex functions? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It's a direct application of Karamata's inequality.
Just have to check that $\sum x_i \geq \sum y_i$ for the points that were chosen.